# Use PowerShell as defaut Shell but discard it during runtime for batch file

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I use `PowerShell` as my default shell in `Dockerfile` to accomplish some tasks, such as add new users and groups to my container build.

**DockerFile (relevant)**

```
SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]
RUN New-LocalUser -Name "testuser" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "CrackPassword!" -Force) -FullName "Test.User" -Description "LocalAdministrator"
RUN Add-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators -Member  testuser -Verbose
RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/InstallUtil.exe" /username=.\testuser /password=CrackPassword! /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack TestDockerService.exe
```

Within the same `DockerFile`, I specify a CMD to run a batch file when the `Docker container` runs.

```
COPY testbat.bat /testbat.bat
CMD testbat.bat && cmd
```

The image builds fine, but `Docker Run` doesn't work, complains :

```
At line:1 char:111
+ ... rence = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue'; testbat.bat && cmd
+                                                                    ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

I guessed there was an issue with running CMD inside a SHELL, and some quick research has demonstrated it may be so...

Is there any way to close the `SHELL` session invoked, or `overrride` it with CMD during run time?

Comment: What is `cmd testbat.bat && cmd` supposed to *do*, though? You could just to `CMD testbat.bat` -- PowerShell is smart enough to use `cmd` to invoke batch files. If you wanted to be explicit about it, `CMD cmd testbat.bat` should do. If you need `cmd` to hang around as the shell after running `testbat.bat`, use the `/k` option.

Comment: I used the explicit option, `CMD cmd testbat.bat`, running the docker container doesn't give an error now, but it doesn't do anything either. The script is just turning Echo on and printing folder contents using dir (folder is C:, so not empty), but the only thing it prints on screen is : `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`, after which container exits and powershell prompt comes back on (host OS powershell)

Comment: I forget how to pass arguments "properly" in a Docker script, but try `cmd /c testbat.bat` or `cmd "/c testbat.bat"` or even `-Command cmd /c testbat.bat`. You can also try `notexist.bat` to verify `cmd` is actually trying to run anything.

Comment: Does it behave differently if you run the batch file using Start-Process to launch cmd.exe with arguments?
Also bear in mind that for cmd you may need to be specific about the batch file path rather than rely on relative pathing

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried every way, but it still wouldn't...execute the batch file, I commented out all `PowerShell` related commands and then tried the same, still nothing. However, keeping the `Powershell` related commands commented, and running `CMD testbat.bat && cmd`, it did the trick. So I suppose it is necessary, but again, the original issue, I cannot run CMD in conjunction with a default shell already specified...I need those powershell commands to install the service, and later a batch file to start the service.

Comment: Whatever the batch file is doing almost certainly can be written as a PowerShell script as well (`Start-Service`, `sc.exe`), so if that's the only reason you're keeping `cmd` around it's probably not a good reason. If you really want `cmd` to be the host shell, on the other hand, you could just turn it around, keep that as the shell and invoke `PowerShell` as a separate command.

Comment: OK, I'll try and reverse it, i.e., I'll run `powershell.exe` instead of in a `SHELL` and invoke `CMD` on the batch file.

Answer (score 3):

Try add following before CMD according to [doc for Shell](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#SHELL)

```
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
```